# Highlight characters in a String in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build an autocomplete component where the relevant characters are highlighted in the search  suggestions as the user types.

The way I have come up to highlight the characters is this JSX

```
{suggestion.substring(0, ind) +
                <mark>{suggestion.substring(ind, val.length)}</mark> +
                suggestion.substring(val.length, suggestion.length)}
```

but it renders an `[Object Object] instead of the string.

How can I correct this?

Here's my whole code

```
      searchSuggestions
        .filter((suggestion) => {
          const lowerSuggestion = suggestion.toLowerCase();
          const val = eventValue.toLowerCase();
          console.log("lowersuggestion is", lowerSuggestion, val);
          return lowerSuggestion.indexOf(val) > -1;
        })
        .map((suggestion) => {
          const lowerSuggestion = suggestion.toLowerCase();
          const val = eventValue.toLowerCase();
          const ind = lowerSuggestion.indexOf(val);
          console.log("ind is", ind, typeof suggestion);
          return (
            <div>
              {suggestion.substring(0, ind) +
                <mark>{suggestion.substring(ind, val.length)}</mark> +
                suggestion.substring(val.length, suggestion.length)}
            </div>
          );
        })
```

Assuming `searchSuggestions` is an array of string. How should I go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with the JSX itself, I solved it by changing it to

```
{suggestion.substring(0, ind)}
              <mark style={{ backgroundColor: "#f7e7d0" }}>
                {suggestion.substring(ind, ind + val.length)}
              </mark>
              {suggestion.substring(ind + val.length, suggestion.length)}
```

Answer (score 1):

`<mark` is a JSX element - which is an object. When you interpolate it (or most objects) into a string, you'll get `[object Object]`.

Use an array instead, so that it gets interpolated into the JSX, rather than interpolated into a string.

```
<div>
    {[
        suggestion.substring(0, ind),
        <mark>{suggestion.substring(ind, val.length)}</mark>,
        suggestion.substring(val.length, suggestion.length)
    ]}
</div>
```

Comment: This is also a nice workaround. But why does using an array interpolates it? could you give a link to the doc?

Comment: Using `+` when either side is a string will result in string concatenation. That's just how JavaScript works. An array does not get concatenated like a string - the JSX parser parses each element separately.